# Report performance (NFR) issues through SonarQube Static Code Analysis

Tags: sonarqube

Can SonarQube static analysis list out the performance issues within the code being scanned? (e.g. doing string concatenation with "+" instead of using StringBuffer).

Are there any rules to be enabled?

Comment: Uhm... Yes, and yes. Perhaps you want to [edit] your question to expand on it?

Comment: We have SonarQube used for static code analysis and checkmarx for security code check. I want to unable rules which check for Performance issues. Is there any list from SonarQube available which are tagged for Performance check which we can enable?